# Filter JSON list when page loads with URL parameters not working

Tags: javascript

I just began learning Front End, and while doing a random project to test, I've stumbled upon an issue that I can't seem to find the right answer for.

I have a page that displays a list from a JSON, and I've set it up to filter through it by a search bar or by click action on the links on the page.

I am trying now to filter it by URL parameters, to show up as filtered by default according to those, when the page loads.

```html
<div class="flex-item" id="analize-list">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <input type="search" id="search" data-search placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div cass="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell nume-analiza-table table-headers">Object name</div>
            <div class="divTableCell pret-table table-headers" >Price</div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-cards" data-item-cards-container></div>
        <template data-item-template>
            <div class="card">
                <div cass="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell nume-analiza-table" data-header></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell pret-table" data-price></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
```

```js
//URL search
var url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
var url = new URL(url_string);
var categoryURL = url.searchParams.get("category");


//search bar
const itemCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-item-template]")
const itemCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-item-cards-container]")
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]")

const menuHematologie = document.querySelector("[data-hematologie")

let items = []

searchInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
var value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
items.forEach(item => {
const isVisible =
  item.object.toLowerCase().includes(value)
item.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
})
})


fetch("list.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
items = data.map(item => {
  const card = itemCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
  const header = card.querySelector("[data-header]")
  const body = card.querySelector("[data-body]")
  const price = card.querySelector("[data-price]")
  header.textContent = item.object
  // body.textContent = item.categorie
  price.textContent = item.price
  itemCardContainer.append(card)
  return { object: item.object, category: item.category, price: item.price, element: card }
})
})

//click search
document.getElementById('category-1').addEventListener('click', () => {
items.forEach(item => {
const isVisible =
  item.category.toLowerCase().includes("category-1")
item.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
})
})

//URL
getURL = function(){
  items.forEach(item => {
    const isVisible =
      item.category.toLowerCase().includes(categoryURL)
    item.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)
    })
}
getURL();
```

Code used here: https://codepen.io/elyiz/pen/qZYQLg

JSON looks like this:

```
 {
  "object": "Umbrella",
  "price": 18,
  "category": "Hallway"
 },
 {
  "object": "Toothbrush",
  "price": "1",
  "category": "Bathroom"
 },
[...]
```

I've managed to get the parameter value from the URL and save it.
Example: URL = example.com/page/?catagory=hallway saved "hallway" in a variable

But I can't get it to work to filter the list (code I've tried last time is under "URL" comment at the end of JS code.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not just send us to external platforms such as codepen.

Comment: @CBroe sorry for that, when I did this previously, it was suggested that it's too much code. Edited with the important code

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell (can't properly debug this here, because the fetch request is not going to work here, or in the codepen) - but I am guessing the asynchronous nature of the fetch request is probably at fault here - `items` is likely not populated by the time you call `getURL();` Try and put that call _into_ the `.then(data => {...}` callback, after you create `items` in there.